Use Azure Pipeline UI or queue-time variable valueas optional with fallback default value
In Azure Pipelines, I need to have an optional variable (say BuildConfiguration) set either in Pipeline settings UI or at queue time


If the variable exists in Pipeline settings UI or at queue-time, then the corresponding value,
If the variable does not exist, then Release should be the default value,

that should be passed for --configuration in DotNetCoreCLI task for command: build
I tried using --configuration $(BuildConfiguration), but it fails if the variable BuildConfiguration is not defined/set

We can use coalesce to achieve this,
first, we'll get the value to an internal variable, _BuildConfiguration using coalesce with Release as the fallback value,
variables:
  - name: _BuildConfiguration
    value: "$[ coalesce(variables['BuildConfiguration'], 'Release') ]"

then we use the newly defined internal variable to set --configuration,
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: build
    arguments: "--configuration $(_BuildConfiguration)"


You can also use condition in a task to create output variable and use it in the subsequent tasks.
# - bash: |
#     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildConfiguration;]Debug"
#   displayName: 'Set BuildConfiguration at runtime'

- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildConfiguration;]Release"
  condition: eq(variables['BuildConfiguration'], '')
  displayName: 'Set BuildConfiguration to Release if it is empty or doesn't exist'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: build
    arguments: "--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)"


It works whether you define BuildConfiguration in Pipeline settings UI or at runtime.
